# Bash script error server issue

Tags: linux, bash, syntax, scripting

I have the following bash script

```
#!/bin/bash

servers="server1.... server2...."
seconds="3"  # value for servers to differ (in seconds)
now=$(date +%s)
for server in $servers
do
    ssh -l root ${server} "( date +%s )" > /tmp/.tmpdate
    echo "-" $(date +%s) >> /tmp/.tmpdate
    difference=$(awk -F '-' '{if ($1-$2 < 0) { print $2-$1 } else { print $1-$2} }' /tmp/.tmpdate)
    if [[ $difference -le $seconds ]] ; then
        echo $server - IN SYNC
    else
        echo $server - NOT IN SYNC 
    fi
done
```

I'm getting a syntax error for the `difference=$(awk -F '-' '{if ($1-$2 < 0) { print $2-$1 } else { print $1-$2} }' /tmp/.tmpdate)` line which is causing the rest of the script to be inaccurate. Any ideas?

Comment: Providing the *exact* error would be helpful. Standing alone, the `awk` line works perfectly! (Also, awk questions should be tagged `awk`; it's a separate programming language, not part of bash/shell syntax).

Comment: ...now, there are also a bunch of quoting issues here, and some of those are obligatory due to treating a string (`servers`) as if it were an array instead of using a real bash array, but those won't be responsible for your immediate issue here unless you're dealing with surprising data in your values.

Comment: try removing the space between `-F` and the `'-'` separator. to `awk -F'-' '{if ($1-$2 < 0) { print $2-$1 } else { print $1-$2} }' /tmp/.tmpdate`

Comment: @QuoVadis, I'm curious -- on which implementation is that called for? (It's GNU awk where I tested the existing awk command to work).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy  sun0S ;-).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can simplify a few:

```
#!/bin/bash 

servers="server1.... server2...."
seconds="3"  # value for servers to differ (in seconds)
for server in $servers
do
  remote=$(ssh -l root ${server}  date +%s ) 
  now=$(date +%s)
  if [ "$remote" -gt "$now" ]
  then
    diff=$(expr $remote - $now)
  else
    diff=$(expr $now - $remote)
  fi
  echo $diff

  if [[ $diff -gt $seconds ]] ; then
    echo $server - NOT IN SYNC 
  else
    echo $server - IN SYNC
  fi
done
```

Comment: Modern math syntax -- `if (( remote > now )); then diff=$(( remote - now )); else diff=$((now - remote)); fi` -- might be preferable. `$(( ))` is actually part of the POSIX sh standard, so even if you wanted to support /bin/sh, there's still no need for expr.

Comment: Personally, I prefer "declare -i". But always trying to adapt the answer to the style of the question.

Comment: `$(( ... ))` is POSIX; `declare` is pure bashism (even its closest family, ksh, uses `typeset` instead). Simply from a portability perspective, it's not necessarily the best choice.

Comment: I made one adjustment to the above syntax that I moved the `now=$(date +%s)` to after the `remote=$(ssh -l root ${server}  date +%s ) ` to check the time after ssh to allow for connection times

Comment: @Pol, good idea, updated in the answer. I must then assume the remainder fulfills your request?

Comment: @pasabaporaqui yes thank you for your suggestion, it looks to be doing it's job perfectly